# Prevent threading in emails from gravity forms

Tags: plugin-gravity-forms

I'm hosting a WP site using gravity forms for a medical clinic.  I'm hoping to add a unique ID of some sort (A timestamp would be enough) to the subject line of emails sent from gravity forms.  Occasionally, emails sent from the site can become threaded where replying to one thread will include messages from previous form submissions.  Obviously this is not acceptable in a medical context.  I can't find any fields or plugins that support this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually utilize Gravity Forms merge tags in the subject line to do what you're asking.

1. Head to the notification settings for your specific form
2. Click on the admin notification for your form (the one that's sending you the emails)
3. On the subject line field, note the icon at the right of the field, you can click on that to access all the fields from that specific form including date (the date of the form submission).
4. Enter `{date_mdy}` for the date to make it unique for your subject lines.

[image: Gravity Form Subject Line tags]

Here are the Gravity Forms Merge Tags docs https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/merge-tags/